# Silverlight bubble chart

Tags: silverlight, bubble-chart

Can someone please tell me where I can find proper bubble chart tutorial in silverlight platform? I found few on net but, they were not meant for beginners. I have just started working on this platform. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will not get it man.. Forget that!!